# Dependency Injection in Angular 2

Tags: dependency-injection, angular, angular2-services

I thought DI was implemented to allow use the same services over the application, and change them as needed. However this snippet (Angular 2.0.0-beta.0) refuses to work:

```ts
# boot.ts
import {ProjectService} from './project.service'

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ProjectService]);



# my.component.ts
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(project: ProjectService) {
    }
}
```

and with explicit service requirement it works:

```ts
# my.component.ts
import {ProjectService} from './project.service';
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(project: ProjectService) {
    }
}
```

The official doc is somewhat inconsistent, but has the same in the plunkr example:

```ts
# boot.ts
import {HeroesListComponent} from './heroes-list.component';
import {HeroesService}       from './heroes.service';

bootstrap(HeroesListComponent, [HeroesService])



# heroes-list.component.ts
import {HeroesService} from './heroes.service';
```

Is this the intended way of DI usage? Why we have to import service in every class requiring it, and where are the benefits if we can't just describe the service once on boot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really related to dependency injection. You can't use a class in TS that is not imported.

This line references a class and DI derives from the type what instance to inject.

```ts
constructor(project: ProjectService) {
```

If the type isn't specified by a concrete import, DI can't know which of all possible `ProjectService` classes should be used.

What you can do for example, is to request a type (`ProjectService`) and get a different implementation (subclass like `MockProjectService` or `EnhancedProjectService`,...)

```ts
bootstrap(HeroesListComponent, [provide(ProjectService useClass: MockProjectService)]);
```

this way DI would inject a `MockProjectService` for the following constructor

```ts
 constructor(project: ProjectService) {
```

Comment: I've thought import in the boot.ts and DI should be enough. Do you mean every possible implementation in every depending file should be imported? E.g. if we have a `ProjectService` for app, and a `MockProjectService` for tests — should both of them be imported into every file using those services?

Comment: No, you only need to import the type you use in the constructor. The alternative implementations need to be imported where you directly reference them. For example for this line `bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(ProjectService, useClass, MockProjectSerivce)])` you need to import `ProjectService` **and** `MockProjectService` because you reference them both.

Comment: I mean a bit different thing: is it designed the `ProjectService` should be referenced **both** in `boot.ts` and the component files related on this service (`my.component.ts`), or do I miss something while implementing it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your last question. Are you talking about `@Components({providers: ...})`? If you should list the classes there?

Comment: I mean now I have to do `import {ProjectService}    from './project.service';` **both** in the `boot.ts` and `my.component.ts` (and every other component  which relies on this service), which feels wrong.

Comment: That was already your initial question. Imports are not related to DI. Imports are required by TS. If you use `constructor(projectService: ProjectService) { projectService./* here you won't get autocompletion without importing ProjectService */ }`. Autocompletion also wouldn't work here if DI weren't involved at all.